# Por que não consigo alterar uma variável em C realizando uma operação aritimética com ela?

Tags: c, matemática

Não estou conseguindo obter o resultado esperado:

bibliotecas
...

```
int main (void){
    float c,r;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Digite o salário\n");
    scanf("%f",&c);
    printf("Digite o reajuste percentual:\n");
    scanf("%f",&r);
    r=r*0,01;
    c=(c* r)+c;
    printf("Salário reajustado: %.2f\n",c);
    return 0;
    }
```

O resultado sempre sai com a primeira leitura da variável `c`, que seria o salário inicial, como faço para ela ser "atualizada" na operação logo abaixo sem ter que adicionar mais variáveis?

Da seguinte forma funciona:

bibliotecas
...

```
int main (void){
    float c,r,n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    printf("Digite o salário\n");
    scanf("%f",&c);
    printf("Digite o percentual de reajuste:\n");
    scanf("%f",&r);
    n=c+r*c;
    printf("Salário reajustado: %.2f\n",n);
    return 0;
    }
```

Mas além da variável adicional, o usuário teria de adicionar o reajuste entre um número real de 0 a 1, sem falar que tenho certeza de que precisarei usar isso no futuro. Como posso solucionar?

Answer (score 2):

Não use vírgula para casas decimais, use ponto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    float c, r;
    printf("Digite o salário\n");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("Digite o reajuste percentual:\n");
    scanf("%f", &r);
    r *= 0.01;
    c = c * r + c;
    printf("Salário reajustado: %.2f\n", c);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/CwE1d1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bphiurwe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/DoubleLiteral.c).

Só tome cuidado que este código tem diversos outros problemas, não ache que só porque está funcionando que está certo.

Comment: Valeu mano, e valeu pelo aviso também, to lendo meu primeiro livro sobre C, e esse programa era pedido num exercício do primeiro capítulo, fiz o fluxograma e quando fui passar pro compilador tinha dado nisso, poderia me indicar os outros problemas que existem nele?

Comment: Dinheiro não pode ser representado com `float`, está misturando com `double` e mais algumas coisas que só vale a pena ver quando tiver avançado mais.

Comment: Ahh, sim, no próprio livro fala sobre os outros tipos que só seriam vistos posteriormente, por enquanto só foi visto float e int mesmo, na correção ta como mostrei o exercício da segunda maneira

Comment: Espero que não, livros não deveriam ensinar tão informalmente, a não ser que faça ressalvas.

Comment: Creio que a ressalva era que os demais tipos não haviam sido vistos ainda, o livro é "Algoritmos e Lógica de Programação em C, Uma Abordagem Didática" do brasileiro Silvio do Lago Pereira, editora Érica.